# What is the limiting sum of $\frac{1}{1\left(3\right)}+\frac{1}{3\left(5\right)}+\frac{1}{5\left(7\right)}+···+\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}=\frac{n}{2n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know $a$ (first term) is $\frac{1}{3}$, but I'm not sure what the common ratio would be from this. I assume it is the $\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}$, but this is not a number. Any hints?

Comment: This is not a geometric series, so talking about common ratio doesn't make much sense. You already have the sum so perhaps you want to know how to get that. So here is a hint: $\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n+1}\right]$. Hope you have heard of *telescoping series*.

Comment: What are you trying to ask?
Is it 'what is the limiting sum' or 'why is the limiting sum $\frac{n}{2n+1}$'

Answer (score 4):

Hint:
$$\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}=\frac12\frac{(2n+1)-(2n-1)}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}=\frac12\left[\frac1{2n-1}-\frac1{2n+1}\right]$$

Comment: how did you get from the first step to the second step when you split the fraction?

Comment: Whenever there is more than  one term in the denominator it is quite common to separating them into different fractions by manipulating the numerator. This a guide to breaking rational expressions into partial fractions: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra-home/alg-rational-expr-eq-func/alg-partial-fraction/v/partial-fraction-expansion-1
You will get the idea from here.

Comment: Hmm I don't get how you managed to separate it into partial fractions if the numerator is just a 1. Isn't this only possible if the numerator is a linear function?

Comment: also, now if I just take the limit n approaches infinity, doesn't it become $\frac{1}{2}$ times $0$ which is = $0$?

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{2n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2+\frac1n}=\frac12$.

Answer (score 0):

The common term can be written as $\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n+1}\right]$.

Thus, the series can be written as:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{2i-1}-\frac{1}{2i+1}\right]=\frac{n}{2n+1}$$ where $i$ is a positive integer.

Now you can find the limit easily, either by using the definition of limit, or using the L'Hospital method.

Comment: How did you split the fraction in the first step?

Comment: @user71207 note that $\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}$ can be written as $\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{(2n+1)-(2n-1)}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}\right]$

Comment: Ok after expanding that makes sense. How was I supposed to think of this myself though? Is there a name for this trick for practice?

Comment: @user71207 you've to look at the denominator and think about how you can manipulate the numerator to split it into two (or more) parts.

Answer (score 0):

$$S=\frac12\big(\frac{1}{2-1}-\frac{1}{2+1}+\frac{1}{4-1}-\frac{1}{4+1}+ \frac{1}{6-1}-\frac{1}{6+1}+\cdot\cdot\cdot+\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n+1}\big) $$

Cancelling similar terms we finally get:

$$S= \frac12\big(1-\frac{1}{2n+1}\big)=\frac12\times\frac{2n}{2n+1}$$

$$\lim _{n→∞ } S=\frac{1}{2}$$